Is there a way to kick off a group of tasks after a test run has completed (copy reports to alternate locations)?
After completing our tests, we are looking to archive our feature reports in a couple different locations, based on the tests ran (regressions, daily, adhoc folders).  We tried to use an afterFeature hook in the config, but since the reports are not yet generated unitl the run is complete, we get an error for the target folder not found.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: target/karate-reports/karate-summary.html (No such file or directory).
Is there a possible way to copy the in memory files to the desired locations or build an after run hook to copy the files.
Currently we have a job that runs on an interval and pulls the files from the target folder, but we would like to be able to do this at runtime so we have current results rather than previous day(s) results.
Test are executed in various ways, such as run option of scenario or feature, runner, and/or mvn commands depending on who or what process starts the tests.

not sure if any previous answers have helped since none have been upvoted or accepted, so will pass

Unsure why acceptance or such is required to get answers to more questions.  That is not even a requirement of stackOverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer Not every user comes back to accept an answer or https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept the first answer you receive. - and noted as an optional attribute since it is not mandatory.  Additionally, many of my post's responses received are simply comments to the post rather than answers, so nothing to accept.

you are right, there is no compulsion to accept answers and there is no compulsion to answer questions in the first place, it is an honor system in some ways. also, in theory - anyone in the community should be able to step up and answer questions, if you don't get an answer it is a sign that the question does not make sense

Since it sounds like from your question that your project uses Maven, you can use maven-antrun-plugin which provides the capability to run tasks(like copying files) at different parts of the lifecycle using maven directly inside of your POM.
You just need to add the following as a plugin to your POM and update the paths for your needs. Also note the phase, which for your use case is post-integration-test but could be any part of the lifecycle.
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.8</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        <configuration>
            <tasks>
                <copy todir="/path/to/alternate/location">
                    <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/target/karate-reports" />
                </copy>
            </tasks>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>


FYI: [INFO] --- antrun:1.8:run (default) @ DP-API --- [WARNING]  Parameter 'tasks' is deprecated: Use target instead [WARNING] Parameter tasks is deprecated, use target instead

This only appear to kick off when I run a mvn install command and is never triggered when running commands via the karate plugin (run command) or runner.

sorry just now getting back to you. did you ever find a solution for this? I reckon you could do something in pure java where you create a copy reports method and use it in the testParallel runner method. I would be willing to take a stab at it if you still need it.

Unfortunately, I have not revisited this since the above issue
